# Extend a given pdf

Tags: pdf

I read a paper and I want to write some notes right after it finishes. Also, I would like to update this note later. Is there a convenient way to do that? I know I can just create a new pdf and combine to the paper pdf but it is not very convenient.

Alternatively,  I do not mind if the notes are before the paper.

Comment: This is a classical implementation suited to [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). Just insert `\includepdf{paper.pdf}` where you want to include the entire paper (at the start with notes at the end, or *vice versa*).

Comment: If you want to annotate the pdf itself, you are better off using tools in your pdf viewer than trying to use tex. You could layer stuff over pages of the pdf as over an image, but that is most definitely not convenient!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use pdfpages package to import the given pdf, then add what you want and compile the whole thing as one file.  Don't know if that's what you wanted, though.